# How to add factor to a tibble using dplyr pipe

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, forcats

I have the following data frame:

```r
dat <- structure(list(genes = c("SPATA6", "PRKCA", "IFI44", "CD34", 
"STAT5A", "SPP1", "IFI44", "UGCG", "RUNX2", "POLB"), tissue = c("P-MSC", 
"fBM-MSC", "vBM-MSC", "A-MSC", "A-MSC", "P-MSC", "fBM-MSC", "P-MSC", 
"fBM-MSC", "fBM-MSC"), tpm = c(3.20952419313059, 2.10173208901973, 
0.191585903686574, 0.70984187675755, 1.13513749520554, 5.37796566842205, 
1.04686030297216, 2.60310788820118, 2.21414404845853, 3.82316169950135
)), .Names = c("genes", "tissue", "tpm"), row.names = c(NA, -10L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
dat 
#>     genes  tissue       tpm
#> 1  SPATA6   P-MSC 3.2095242
#> 2   PRKCA fBM-MSC 2.1017321
#> 3   IFI44 vBM-MSC 0.1915859
#> 4    CD34   A-MSC 0.7098419
#> 5  STAT5A   A-MSC 1.1351375
#> 6    SPP1   P-MSC 5.3779657
#> 7   IFI44 fBM-MSC 1.0468603
#> 8    UGCG   P-MSC 2.6031079
#> 9   RUNX2 fBM-MSC 2.2141440
#> 10   POLB fBM-MSC 3.8231617
```

At the moment I'm sorting the factor using this code:

```r
dat$tissue <- factor(dat$tissue, levels = c("fBM-MSC", "vBM-MSC", "A-MSC", "P-MSC"))
```

My question his how can I perform the same operation using dplyr's pipe from initial `dat`?

Comment: Like this? `dat <- dat %>% mutate(tissue = factor(tissue, levels = c("fBM-MSC", "vBM-MSC", "A-MSC", "P-MSC"))`

Comment: Or even `dat <- dat %>% mutate(tissue = factor(tissue))`

Comment: @fugu I want it to be specifically ordered in this way `c("fBM-MSC", "vBM-MSC", "A-MSC", "P-MSC"))`

Comment: Then you need to arrange your data too: `dat <- dat %>% mutate(tissue = factor(tissue)) %>% arrange(tissue = factor(tissue, levels = c("fBM-MSC", "vBM-MSC", "A-MSC", "P-MSC")))`